# Touchpad disabled after resume when previously using usb mouse

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, mouse, dell, touchpad

After upgrading from xubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 my touchpad stopped working in certain circumstances.

In work I use a USB mouse, in the evening I undock my Dell latitude and close the lid to suspend to RAM. When I get home and resume, my touchpad no longer works. The mouse pointer appears frozen in place.

As an experiment I brought home my USB mouse one day, and this still worked. It appears that for some reason my touchpad is disabled after a resume.

How do I get my touchpad to work without restarting X ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the mouse module becomes non-functional, and needs to be reloaded.

My solution was to reload the mouse module. This makes my touchpad work again.

Unfortunately you need sudo to do this.

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse
```